# Error when trying to send meta-transaction

Tags: ethers.js, openzeppelin, meta-transactions

I am getting this error when trying to send a meta-transaction:

```
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (data="0x", transaction={"to":"0xbBB6E97CA58B081f0A70Ad30A313A833536DA759","data":"0x2d0335ab0000000000000000000000003e2f11e9a522e7ae74e38a01776c9cf2bf7fc55c","accessList":null}, error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":45,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0xbbb6e97ca58b081f0a70ad30a313a833536da759\",\"data\":\"0x2d0335ab0000000000000000000000003e2f11e9a522e7ae74e38a01776c9cf2bf7fc55c\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":45,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com"}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

This is my code:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { createInstance } from './forwarder';
import { signMetaTxRequest } from './signer';

async function sendTx(asset: any, toAddress: string) {
  console.log(`Sending mint tx to mint to=${toAddress}`);
  return asset.mint(toAddress);
}

async function sendMetaTx(asset: any, provider: any, signer: any, toAddress: string) {
  console.log(`Sending mint meta-tx to mint to=${toAddress}`);
  const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBHOOK_URL;
  if (!url) throw new Error(`Missing relayer url`);

  const forwarder = createInstance(provider);
  const from = await signer.getAddress();
  const data = asset.interface.encodeFunctionData('mint', [toAddress]);
  const to = asset.address;
  
  const request = await signMetaTxRequest(signer.provider, forwarder, { to, from, data });

  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(request),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
}

export async function claimReward(asset: any, provider: any) {
  if (!window.ethereum) throw new Error(`User wallet not found`);

  await window.ethereum.enable();
  const userProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const userNetwork = await userProvider.getNetwork();
  if (userNetwork.chainId !== 80001) throw new Error(`Please switch to Mumbai for signing`);

  const signer = userProvider.getSigner();
  const from = await signer.getAddress();
  const balance = await provider.getBalance(from);
  
  const canSendTx = balance.gt(1e15);
  if (canSendTx) return sendTx(asset.connect(signer), from);
  else return sendMetaTx(asset, provider, signer, from);
}

import { signTypedMessage } from 'eth-sig-util';

const EIP712Domain = [
  { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' }
];

const ForwardRequest = [
  { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
];

function getMetaTxTypeData(chainId: any, verifyingContract: any) {
  return {
    types: {
      EIP712Domain,
      ForwardRequest,
    },
    domain: {
      name: 'MinimalForwarder',
      version: '0.0.1',
      chainId,
      verifyingContract,
    },
    primaryType: 'ForwardRequest',
  }
};

async function signTypedData(signer: any, from: any, data: any) {
  // If signer is a private key, use it to sign
  if (typeof(signer) === 'string') {
    const privateKey = Buffer.from(signer.replace(/^0x/, ''), 'hex');
    return signTypedMessage(privateKey, { data });
  }

  // Otherwise, send the signTypedData RPC call
  // Note that hardhatvm and metamask require different EIP712 input
  const isHardhat = data.domain.chainId == 31337;
  const [method, argData] = isHardhat
    ? ['eth_signTypedData', data]
    : ['eth_signTypedData_v4', JSON.stringify(data)]
  return await signer.send(method, [from, argData]);
}

export async function buildRequest(forwarder: any, input: any) {
  const nonce = await forwarder.getNonce(input.from).then((nonce: any) => nonce.toString());
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}

export async function buildTypedData(forwarder: any, request: any) {
  const chainId = await forwarder.provider.getNetwork().then((n: any) => n.chainId);
  const typeData = getMetaTxTypeData(chainId, forwarder.address);
  return { ...typeData, message: request };
}

export async function signMetaTxRequest(signer: any, forwarder: any, input: any) {
  const request = await buildRequest(forwarder, input);
  console.log(request);
  const toSign = await buildTypedData(forwarder, request);
  const signature = await signTypedData(signer, input.from, toSign);
  return { signature, request };
}
```

I am using OpenZeppelin Defender as relayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the error is happening in this line of code, inside `buildRequest` function:

`const nonce = await forwarder.getNonce(input.from).then((nonce: any) => nonce.toString());`

It seems that the `nonce` is not being calculated correctly using the `getNonce` function from the `forwarder`.

As this is an account that has no transactions, I have replaced that function by this and it worked:

```
export async function buildRequest(provider: any, input: any) {
  let nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(input.from);
  nonce = nonce.toString();
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}
```